# RadBeacon USB install

Tags: ibeacon

I purchased a RadBeacon USB from Radius Networks and iBeacon Locator on my Nexus 7 says the calibration is: -59.
My iPhone 5s sees it, the measured power is: -64, so I press OK to copy this value to the Measure Power field of the beacon settings. You must apply the settings to update the Measured Power on the beacon device.
So I press Apply and use the PIN 0000.
Apply Settings.
It says "Invalid PIN".
I use my 4 digit PIN that I use for everything and it says "Connection timed out".

Now in the instructions it says "If you are unable to discover you beacon using the RadBeacon Config App, remove the plastic cover and firmly press the configuration button above and to the right of the battery holder.  This will restart the 30 minute configuration window and your beacon should show up in subsequent scans.

1. Define firmly.
2. I didn't think it had a battery.  What is a battery holder?
3. Does this button give any kind of tactile feedback when pressed so that I can know that I'm pressing it?
4. There's a square opening on the top-right of both sides after removing the metal cover. Is one of them the button?
5. Is there a product that doesn't have this 30 minute restriction so that I can get it to work the first time as a proof-of-concept, and not have to worry about it being bricked after 30 minutes?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry you are having trouble, Philip.

You are correct that your RadBeacon USB does not have a battery.  We also sell a RadBeacon tag, which does have a battery and it sounds like you are reading the instructions for that model.  So please ignore those instructions.

To restart the config time window on your RadBeacon USB, simply unplug it and plug it back in.  Then try using the iPhone RadBeacon app to configure it using the default pin of 0000.  If it does not accept that pin, and you did not change the pin to something else you remember, contact us at support@radiusnetworks.com and we will arrange a replacement.

Understand that the configuration time window is simply a security feature to keep other folks from trying to reconfigure your beacon.  You can always restart the time window by cycling power.  So you don't need to worry about bricking your device -- just be careful not to change the pin without writing down the new number.